# How to update item quantity in the shopping cart using React JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, crud

ecommerce update cart item quantity on button click?
I'm making a card. has a certain quantity that has a button on it I want to click on the button to increase the amount

Comment: Please, share a reproducible example of your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use useState hook. The use state variable will be your cart quantity and the function will add value to the previous variable.

Here is a simple example how you can do that:

```
function App() {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState(0)
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>cart quantity: {cart}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCart(cart + 1)}>Button</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```